# nested vlookup in excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I need to search a spreadsheet for multiple criteria.

[image]

Say that I want to pull the batch # with given criteria from the 837 file and type of file. For instance if the values I am searching for are 2456 and 999 I want to get 2499. How would I create a formula for this? I tried to use an index and match formula but could not get that to work.

I tried to concantenate but the value is pulling incorrectly.

[image]

An Index/Match Formula pulls #N/A

[image]

Comment: It would be a good idea to show what you've tried before this question starts getting down-voted.

Comment: *hint:* you can use an Index match **array** formula with multiple match criteria

Comment: You could concatenate the fields in columns A and B in a new column and use that for your VLOOKUP.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the advise, I deleted my attempts but I will try to re-create.

Comment: @TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch I tried concatenating the columns but the formula is pulling a #N/A value, or just the wrong value all together and I know I am doing the vlookup formula correct just for a test I put the concantinate in column C and moved C to D(=vlookup("2456 999", C2:D5,2).

Comment: I have also noticed that 2456 in rows 4 and 5 is showing an error note. This often means that the numbers are actually text-that-look-like-numbers and may have trailing spaces. Please clarify the situation and possibly correct your data. A quick Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Finish should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pairs of *837File* and *type of file* are unique then a simple [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) will suffice.

```
=sumifs(C:C, A:A, 2456, B:B, 999)
'or with 2456 in Y2 and 999 in Z2 as,
=sumifs(C:C, A:A, Y2, B:B, Z2)
```

If the the pairs of *837File* and *type of file* are not unique then you need to specify how you want to handle multiple returns.

Comment: This Worked. Always something much simpler than I was trying. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A=2456)*(B:B=999),0))`

Remember to enter the formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER